# calling of function of a class by using its name

Tags: python, object, reflection

I'm trying to simplify this code, which when I look at other methods to do this, is way less shorter, and my solution could be error prone as there could be no module or class level in the function string definition

```
function_string = 'api.components.ImageAnnotationHandler.action'
mod_name, class_name, func_name = function_string.rsplit('.',2)
mod = importlib.import_module(mod_name)
my_class = getattr(mod, class_name)()
func = getattr(my_class, func_name)
result = func()
```

How would you address this matter?

Comment: you need to split the function name, and use a loop calling `getattr()` of each.

Comment: How do I know when to instantiate? because that's a problem I face as well

Comment: Instantiate what? Do you mean whether `ImageAnnotationHandler` is an object or a function that needs to be called? You could check the type, but that wouldn't help if the function also needs arguments. I'm not sure how to deal with that in any kind of general way.

Comment: What's the context here - where do the strings come from?

Comment: string comes from an event subscriber system